# Social Network PHP MYSQL table relations

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

I'm an intermediate programmer and still a student as well, I've decided to work on a project of mine that could be called a Social Network.

I'm writing everything from scratch and some of you might say that I reinvent the wheel which I agree but it is for personal purposes and learning oriented efforts.
Please do not recommend existing frameworks because I don't like using them, I'd rather create something on my own and experiment and learn, it is better for me this way.

I'm trying to figure out the efficient way of linking the tables and relations between 
 
user / profile / groups / pages / chat / notifications

What I currently have it is not all I want to implement, there are many things I want to experiment with and get the best practice but I feel like I'm lost here and i can't figure it out. I currently have something like this:

User Table

```
UserID (PK)
Email
Password
FirstName
LastName
Location
Date
Verified
etc..
```

Permissions Table

```
PermissionId (PK)
Permission
```

User_Permissions Table

```
UserID (FK to users)
PermissionId (FK to permissions)
```

Group Table

```
group_id (PK)
group_descrp
```

Chat Table

```
id (PK)
from
to
message
read
time
```

But I just stopped here because I'm kinda confused with them all, I've tried to do them individually and I  can't really figure out the best way to do this and link them all together. I need some advice to put me back on track, if you have anything else to add that might help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: A little Off Topic: IMO the best way to do ANY development is writing in a piece of paper. First all things that you want your APP had. Next, all the tables for that, and all the atributes. Finally wrote the "connections" between those. And convert it to sql. Also if you read the Facebook API you will get a very good reference for all of this :)

Comment: On chat table FROM will be FK to user (ID), same for TO

Comment: You might want to start a bit smaller and add features along the way. Example: Only one group per user, permissions fixed to a role in a static file, one role per user, etc. Dont overstretch and get nothing in the end ;)
Apart from that, that schema doesnt look bad.